# Will gcc-git break my current install?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gcc, glibc

Arch Linux's AUR offers a few versioned packages for GCC, for things that still need an *older* compiler. But the `gcc-git` package does not install to opt, or a subdirectory.

Since the rest of my system was presumably built with the version of GCC that arch ships (11, I believe), will replacing it with 12 break everything? Won't everything no longer have the right libc?

Or is it safe to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the rest of my system was presumably built with the version of GCC that arch ships (11, I believe),

Most of it. You probably have a few odd packages left that were built with older versions. You very likely have some that were built with Clang.

> Won't everything no longer have the right libc?

libc is not part of the compiler. It comes from the Glibc project.

And aside from a few exceptions, C libraries retain compatibility for a long time, changing their 'soname' versions infrequently – Glibc has been at libc.so.6 since around 1997; binaries built then should still generally work with libc.so.6 from today.

Comment: I suppose that shows my ignorance. I inferred that the package "gcc-libs" provided that. But I suppose overall, my question could be re-phrased as: does anything other than gcc depend on gcc's libs?
It's not 100% clear to me, but I think your answer basically equates to: "No, it's fine." Is that right?

Comment: Ah, yes, many programs link to gcc-libs (which is a separate thing from libc), but that too keeps compatibility across many releases.